# What do the commands below mean? x=${1//[^ 0-9]/} and ${#x}

Tags: bash, scripting

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

x=${1//[^0-9]/}
sum=0
for ((i=0; i<${#x}; i++)); do
    ((sum+=${x:i:1}))
done
echo $sum
```

I am new to Linux. Could you explain this code to me step by step, please?
I just wanted to show you in bold which line I don't understand.

---

I have here the answer:

```
$ ./summ_of_digits 115

7
```

---

Task: Forming the digit sum of the arguments

- The program name is the sum of the digits
- The program receives one or more numbers as arguments and calculates for
  each specified number is the sum of the digits.
- Each line of the output contains the number and its sum of digits.
- Example:

```
$ digit sum 19 115

19 10

115 7
```

Comment: It looks like you tried some formatting inside the code; perhaps list the script as-is, then ask your question below it, with any formatting that you think would help. The text in the title also mentions code (`for: { #x}`) that doesn't match anything in the script. Please use the body of your post to describe your question. Thank you!

Comment: given how the original revision was formatted, I took the liberty of assuming the `**`s were for bold. And bolding with them doesn't work in code blocks, and code outside code blocks is unreadable, so I removed those parts. Please [edit] the question if it's wrong now.

Comment: Welcome, please also [edit] the question to show what are the possible values of `$1`. I assume that is a string that contains numbers and other characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x=${1//[^ 0-9]/}
```

`$1` is the first positional parameter / command line argument.

`${var//pattern/replace}` takes the value of `$var` and replaces all occurrences of *pattern* with *replace*. Here, the pattern is `[^ 0-9]`, meaning any single character that is not space or something between `0` to `9`(*). The *replacement* part is empty so those are removed, and the result expanded, and then assigned to `x`.

<sub>(* depending on the locale that could include non-ASCII digits, which probably won't work later in the script with the arithmetic.)</sub>

```
${#x}
```

`${#var}` is the length of the value in the variable.

```
${x:i:1}
```

`${var:position:count}` expands to *count* characters starting at *position* from the value of `$var`, so `${x:i:1}` is the character at position `i`.

See e.g. [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) in Bash's manual.

```
for ((i=0; i<${#x}; i++))
```

And this is an arithmetic loop, a bit like the common form of the `for` loop in C. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html

Note that the character positions are indexed from zero, so in the string `abc`, the `c` is at position 2, and that's why the loop goes from zero to one less than the string length.

It's easy to see that if the script is called as `sumscript.sh 123456789` the output is `45`. Same for `sumscript.sh 1234x5x6789`. Not sure why they'd allow the space though, since it'll produce an error in the arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you a thousand times! I could understand every step!

Comment: @Jana If you see that an answer actually answers your question mark it as accepted.

Comment: Yes, gladly. Where or how could I accept it? There is only "Share" "Edit" "Follow". But I could not see "Accept"

Comment: Accepted! Done! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`x=${1//[^0-9]/}` takes the first argument given to the script and strips any character that is not a digit:

```bsh
$ script 123xxx
# `$1` is equal to 123
```

`for ((i=0; i<${#x}; i++)); do` loops from 0 to the the length of the value of `$x` (3) minus 1 (2):

```
# i is equal in the loop to
0
1
2
```

`((sum+=${x:i:1}))` sums to `sum` in every loop the value of the position of character in `x` given by `i` in the string:

```
0 + 1 = 1
1 + 2 = 3
3 + 3 = 6
```

So the final result of `sum` is 6.

Comment: What do three slashes  //../ and ^ mean here?     x=${1//[^0-9]/}

Comment: @Jana Welcome, It's explained in ikkachus answer.

Comment: @Jana `^` means *not* the subsequent characters.

Comment: Thank you so much!